# Time picker defaults opens at 00:00 irrespective of selection

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

Dynamics CRM 2011 on premise.

On new Appointment and new Service Activity forms, Start Time defaults to now.

However, on opening, the time picker begins at 00:00, rather than a time close to now.

[image]

A user reports that it used to open with the right time selected but broke a couple of months ago after an update.

Can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug. According to Microsoft, it will be fixed "in the future".

https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/p/112983/228137.aspx#228137